# why is my aimation drifting away?

Tags: animation, rigging, mixamo

I have a mixamo animation that I am retargetting to another rig. however when I try, the models start to drift randomly in a direction after retargetting. how can I fix this?

Comment: Does the new armature has the exact same bones?

Comment: No, different rigging